# Backwards compatible python plugin

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I made a plugin for sublime text 2, and now sublime text 3 is out, I ported the plugin to work with sublime text 3. However, I left the sublime text 2 version up as the main version in the package control.

Could I update my package in a way that it works on both sublime text 2 and sublime text 3?

Comment: Can the package test which environment its running in and react accordingly?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what your plugin does, it's very possible to write it in such a way that it is compatible with both ST2 and ST3. If most of the code is compatible, but there are portions that are not, you can use the version number (`sublime.version()`) to determine what version of ST is being used. I believe everything >= 3006 is ST3. If you do need to maintain separate branches, just direct users to the ST3 branch if they are using ST3. Package control, when it is updated, should support this, but I don't know how far wbond is on that.

Answer (score 0):

As a followup, wbond has said recently that Package Control 2.0 should be coming out "soon" though I don't know how long that will be. On the list of things that is being changed is a new json format that will allow specifying if it works in ST2 and/or ST3.